# knockout.js 3.5 not working with ratelimit and arrayChange for same element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am removing an element from an array and adding a new one to it with a ratelimit and listening to the arraychange. It never gets called when I am adding and removing same element.  I am thinking the timeout delays the subscription and it still sees the same array size.  Is there anyway around this for an array size that doesnt change within the ratelimit time?  arrayChange is hit when ratelimit is removed.

```js
function Unscheduled() {
    var self = this;
  self.games = ko.observableArray([]).extend({
            rateLimit: { timeout: 0, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" }});

    self.changes = ko.observable(0);
    self.games.subscribe(function (changes) {
                console.log('Array Hit');
                self.changes(self.changes()+1);
        }, null, "arrayChange");
        
  self.games.push('test');
  
  self.addRemove = function() {
  self.games.remove('test');
  self.games.push('test');
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new Unscheduled());
```

```html
<script src="https://exposureevents.com/scripts/knockout-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="text: changes">

</div>
<button data-bind="click: addRemove">
Add/Remove
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem with the snippet of code is that its removing and adding the same text to the array.  Perhaps the change mechanism is comparing the before and after arrays and because its essentially the same array then there is nothing to notify. When the text added is different each time then it appears to work.

```js
function Unscheduled() {
  var self = this;
  self.games = ko.observableArray([]).extend({
    rateLimit: {
      timeout: 0,
      method: "notifyWhenChangesStop"
    }
  });

  self.changes = ko.observable(0);
  self.games.subscribe(function(changes) {
    console.log('Array Hit');
    self.changes(self.changes() + 1);
  }, null, "arrayChange");

  self.games.push('test');

  self.addRemove = function() {
    self.games.remove(self.games()[0]);
    self.games.push('test'+ self.changes());
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new Unscheduled());
```

```html
<script src="https://exposureevents.com/scripts/knockout-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="text: changes">

</div>
<button data-bind="click: addRemove">
Add/Remove
</button>
```

Comment: Yes I know you are correct in your analysis but how do I get around it?

Comment: There's no way around it. What you're seeing is exactly the way `arrayChange` is supposed to work. See [this KO test](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/2bec689a9a7fcaaed37e6abb9fdec648f86c4f81/spec/observableArrayChangeTrackingBehaviors.js#L557-L562)